# Is not using external style sheet for CSS causing my code not to execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code that you see was kindly given to me by a Stack Overflow user and his JSFiddle can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/f18513hw/. His code works just fine in JSFiddle. I copied and pasted his codes into my Textpad and saved it in my htdocs folder of XAMPP and tried to run it.

I discovered that when I place my cursor on the icon of the cars, the icon magnifies (as it's supposed to) but I get not textbox appearing beneath the icon. That is the whole idea of my webpage, to place one's mouse on an image and a textbox appears and the user then inserts his comments into the box. When I asked Stack Overflow users why no textbox was appearing, a lady kindly pointed out that I was missing the jQuery library link, so I put that in, too.

I have checked and rechecked the layout of the codes (the JavaScript and jQuery link are placed within the head tags, and the CSS codes placed within the style tags) and nothing seems wrong, but the code *still* doesn't run. Since *none* of the scripts are server-side, I decided not to use XAMPP and simply saved the scripts in "My Document" and run it on the browser, but nothing changed. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? If a code runs in JFiddle, is there any rhyme or reason why it should not run on a browser? This is ridiculous.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
        <script>
            $('.car').click(function() {
                $('.comment').css("visibility", "hidden");
                $('#button').css("visibility", "hidden");

                var id = $(this).children('label').attr('for');
                var buttonOffset;
                switch (id) {
                    case 'mercedesbenz':
                        buttonOffset = '0';
                        break;
                    case 'porche':
                        buttonOffset = '33%';
                        break;
                    case 'bmw':
                        buttonOffset = '66%';
                        break;
                }

                $(this).children('.comment').css("visibility", "visible");
                $('#button').css("left", buttonOffset);
                $('#button').css("visibility", "visible");
            });

            $('.comment').mouseleave(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.comment').css("visibility", "hidden");
                    $('#button').css("visibility", "hidden");
                }, 500);
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #form {
                position: absolute;
                overflow: hidden;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                margin-right: -50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
            }
            .car {
                float: left;
                margin: 2% 2% 5% 2%;
            }

            .car label img {
                transform: scale(0.8);
                transition-duration: 0.2s;
            }

            .car label img:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
                transform: scale(1);
            }

            .comment {
                position: absolute;
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            .comment input {
                width: 128px;
                font-size: 1em;
            }

            .car label img {
                width: 128px;
                display: block;
            }

            #button {
                position: relative;
                left: 66%;
                margin: 2%;
                visibility: hidden;
            }
         </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form">
            <form method="post" action="#">
                <div class="car">
                    <label for="mercedesbenz">
                        <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9" />
                    </label>
                    <div class="comment">
                        <input type="text" id="mercedesbenz" placeholder="Merc" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="car">
                    <label for="porche">
                        <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9" />
                    </label>
                    <div class="comment">
                        <input type="text" id="Porche" placeholder="Porc" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="car">
                    <label for="bmw">
                        <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9" />
                    </label>
                    <div class="comment">
                        <input type="text" id="bmw" placeholder="Beemer" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"First of all, I know I am going to get downvoted for asking this question"* - Well then, *don't* ask it until you think you can improve it enough that you won't get down votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is executing BEFORE the DOM has been loaded.  You need to either move your code after your HTML or use `$(document).ready()` to make sure your code is not run too early.

So, when code like this runs:

```
$('.car').click(function() {...});
```

there is no `.car` object yet in the DOM so no event handler can be installed.

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.car').click(function() {...});
});
```

Or, you can move your `<script>` tag right before the `</body>` tag like this so that the DOM elements are already loaded before your script runs:

```
<body>
  ... various HTML
<script>
    $('.car').click(function() {...});
</script>
</body>
```

---

FYI, the default for a jsFiddle is to not run your code until after the DOM is loaded which is not how your code is in the real web page - thus a sometimes difference between a real web page and jsFiddle.  A jsFiddle can be set with a drop-down in the upper left to control when the Javascript runs.

Comment: I've posted a JSFiddle which includes the solution based on the original fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/f18513hw/3/

Comment: jfriend00, you're so right -- I just didn't see that I was putting the cart before the horse. This is due to my lack of experience in coding in JavaScript. Thank you so much for pointing that out.

Comment: Marc, I appreciate your input, too.

Comment: @Jason12 - since it looks like you may be fairly new here at StackOverflow, do you realize that if your question gets answered, you can mark an answer as the best answer by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.   This will earn both you and the person who wrote the answer some reputation points which can earn you privileges here.

Comment: jfriend00, I've just clicked the green checkmark next to your very useful answer, and I've also clicked on the upper triangle next to your answer. I have also just executed my file (by adhering to your advice that jQuery library link and the actual JavaScript should ideally be placed just before the closing body tag) on XAMPP, and it works!!! Thanks again so much.

Answer (score 0):

Insert you javascript code into either `window.onload` or `$(document).ready()` in order to make your code start executing only after the webpage has fully loaded.

Put all your JS code into doStuff();

```
window.onload = doStuff;
function doStuff() {
    ...
}
```

or

```
$(document).ready(doStuff);
```

});

If this doesn't work, try updating your browser.

Comment: `window.onload = doStuff();` would not work as it would execute `doStuff()` immediately.  It would have to be `window.onload = doStuff;`.